# Navigator not showing in high_chart in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, highcharts, flutter-web

I try to implement flutter chart with `high_chart: ^2.0.3` library.
When come to the implement the navigator its not showing on the chart. I enable the navigator but
Chart only show like this.

```
navigator: {
        enabled: true      
},
```

[image]

What i looking for get like this.

[image]

I add the chart data string like this.

```
  final String _chartData = '''{
chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: true      
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
               //data
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Winter 2008-2009',
            data: [
              
                [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  7), 0   ]//data

            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Winter 2009-2010',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9,  9), 0   ],
               //data
            ]
        }],
}''';
```

Also i add this for the index.html file

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

Full source code [Here..](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gTWTLkZPDrpfgyFWhLK9TMiHD8x5kDJEYPdaEY08T8g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You *do* realize that highcharts is free only to try.  If you *use* it, you must buy a commercial license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load Highstock only, Highcharts is already included in Highstock:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/series-label.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hnxvqpyj/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/understanding-highcharts-stock